# Is there a way to get Sims 3 from my Steam account to work on my Mac?

Tags: steam, pc, macos, origin

I previously had a PC and Steam account. Now I have a Mac and I really want to play Sims 3.

I read somewhere that I could download Origin and transfer my codes or something, but how would I go about doing that? Would I have to buy the game on origin?

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://techgage.com/article/migrating_your_ea_games_from_steam_or_retail_to_origin/) covers the process in full; but beware:

The Mac OS X port of The Sims 3 is, in my experience, a shoddy piece of work, and is hardly worth the trouble. (Which is a crying shame, especially given the history of Mac OS ports of the Sims franchise games.)

In short: fetch the CD key from the Steam Library, and redeem it in your Origin library.

You can then use Origin to install the game on Mac OS X.

Comment: Also worth noting is that while the keys you get on Steam can be redeemed in Origin, the keys you get from Origin cannot be redeemed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WineBottler to run Windows applications on a Mac.

Scroll to 04 in WineBottler and click "Install Steam" Login play.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @aytimothy I think you judged this answer too quickly.  While the quality of the writing in the original edit was awful, it did attempt to answer the question. If the suggestion works, it might even be the best answer given that the Mac OS X port is apparently a "shoddy piece of work".

Comment: @RossRidge, although that's a possible way, it's the long way round. Isn't the OP asking for like a Mac version of the game? You know how some games are available for multiple platforms on Steam? (ie. CS:GO is on Mac, Lunix and PC) - He's looking for a way to use the key he has from Steam and put it onto Origin (for Mac, if it has a mac version) then download from there?

Comment: @aytimothy This answer's suggestion actually sounds simpler. No CD keys to copy, just log in to your Steam account using a Winebottle wrapped Steam client. The original poster simply wants to play The Sims 3 on his Mac. While he mentioned he had heard of one possible way to accomplish this, I don't think that means he wouldn't be open to a better alternative. In any case, a bad answer is still an answer.

Answer (score -2):

Log in to your steam account, and download Sims 3, but log in with the same account you buyed the game with, but first make sure if the game is available for Mac.